# array .contains() in swift expecting a thrown bool?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, computer-science, contains

I am trying to check if the array newGames contains a certain object of class Game. If it does, then I will not add it to the array. If it doesn't, I will add it. My code is as follows:

```
for game in allGames{
            if(!newGames.contains(game){
                newGames.append(game)
            }
        }
```

Where `allGames` is an array of object Game

```
var allGames = [Game(id: "5", title: "Dog", release_date: "1989", publisher: "Nintendo", price: "20", platform: "OS X", category: "Adventure", players: ["A", "B"]), Game(id: "5", title: "Dog", release_date: "1989", publisher: "Nintendo", price: "20", platform: "OS X", category: "Adventure", players: ["A", "B"])]
```

However, I'm getting the error `Cannot convert value of type 'Game' to expected argument type '(Game) throws -> Bool'`

Why is this occurring? I've tried both

```
for game in allGames{
            if(!newGames.contains(where: game){
                newGames.append(game)
            }
        }
```

and

```
for game in allGames{
            if(!newGames.contains(game throws -> Bool){
                newGames.append(game)
            }
        }
```

but neither seems to resolve the error and instead only adds to it. What is going on, and why is swift unhappy with the method .contains(game)?

Comment: Nobody even knows what allGames is.

Comment: I've edited the question to provide more info on allGames. It's just an array of games of type Game

Comment: And where does a guy named newGames come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of your `game` instance probably doesn't conform to equatable.

Either add a conformance to equatable to that type.

Answer (score 1):

you have to create a Equatable class to compare objects

```
struct Game: Equatable {
    let data:Bool
}

static func == (fObj:Game, tObj:Game) -> Bool { 
    return fObj.data == fObj:data
}

allGames.contains(yourObject)
```

or filter by id

```
allGames.filter { data in data.id == 1 }
```

Comment: Thanks! I've made Game conform to Equatable using func == but now I'm getting the error ```Cannot convert value of type '(Bool, ())' to expected condition type 'Bool'```. Am I missing something really simple ?

Comment: @rjc810 i've updated my answer, i think you have to use static

Answer (score 0):

Make your Game conforms **Equatable**.

Looks like you have missing/extra bracket in your code snippet

Should be:

```
for game in allGames {
    if !newGames.contains(game) {
        newGames.append(game)
    }
}
```